# Connecting existing nodejs backend project to mongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native

i have an existing nodejs project which works fine without a database. it has all the required files, routes, json arrays for the users, listings etc, but i need to connect it to mongoDB Atlas and im a total beginner in this.

what i tried so far is this:

this is my index.js file from my nodejs project:

```
const mongo = require('./config/mongo');

const express = require("express");
const categories = require("./routes/categories");
const listings = require("./routes/listings");
const listing = require("./routes/listing");
const users = require("./routes/users");
const user = require("./routes/user");
const auth = require("./routes/auth");
const my = require("./routes/my");
const messages = require("./routes/messages");
const expoPushTokens = require("./routes/expoPushTokens");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const compression = require("compression");
const config = require("config");
const app = express();

const userSchema = require("./schemas/userSchema");
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectID


app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compression());

app.use("/api/categories", categories);
app.use("/api/listing", listing);
app.use("/api/listings", listings);
app.use("/api/user", user);
app.use("/api/users", users);
app.use("/api/auth", auth);
app.use("/api/my", my);
app.use("/api/expoPushTokens", expoPushTokens);
app.use("/api/messages", messages);

const port = process.env.PORT || config.get("port");
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}...`);
});


const connectToMongoDB = async () => {
  await mongo().then(async (mongoose) => {
    try {
      
      await new userSchema().save()
      console.log('connectedddd and saved')
    }
    finally {
      mongoose.connection.close()
    }
  })
}
connectToMongoDB()
```

it connects to the stabase just fine, but what i get there is this:

[image]

i also have this `users.js` file which is in the `routes` folder:

```
const mongo = require('../config/mongo');
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Joi = require("joi");
const usersStore = require("../store/users");
const validateWith = require("../middleware/validation");

const schema = {
  name: Joi.string().required().min(2),
  email: Joi.string().email().required(),
  password: Joi.string().required().min(5),
};

router.post("/", validateWith(schema), (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  if (usersStore.getUserByEmail(email))
    return res
      .status(400)
      .send({ error: "A user with the given email already exists." });

  const user = { name, email, password };
  usersStore.addUser(user);

  res.status(201).send(user);
});

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(usersStore.getUsers());
});

module.exports = router;
```

and also this `users.js` file which is in the `store` folder:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Ilir",
    email: "ilir@domain.com",
    password: "12345",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "John",
    email: "john@domain.com",
    password: "12345",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Iris",
    email: "iris@domain.com",
    password: "12345",
  },
];

const getUsers = () => users;

const getUserById = (id) => users.find((user) => user.id === id);

const getUserByEmail = (email) => users.find((user) => user.email === email);

const addUser = (user) => {
  user.id = users.length + 1;
  users.push(user);
};

module.exports = {
  getUsers,
  getUserByEmail,
  getUserById,
  addUser,
};
```

so as you see from the imports in my index.js file, everything is builded properly. what i need is to import all the listings, users, messages etc. to the database and make my app communicate with the database so when i register a new user it populates the database.
just to remind you, it works just fine in localhost without a DB. so the functions are dynamically well connected with each other.

anyone please guide me if not in details, maybe just the steps what i have to take to make this work.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your code creates a new empty user and saves it. The screenshot shows that the user is saved, so this works. What exactly *doesn't* work?

Comment: @RobertKawecki so how do i pass my `users` array (which is in my `routes` folder) to the database. when i do this: `await new userSchema().save({users})` it just adds another empty query in the database. also when i try to register a user from the app (the react-native app which i want to connect) from my real device i get this in the terminal but nothing in the database: https://prnt.sc/10ulos7

Comment: Have you tried `UserModel.create([...users]);`? Also, it looks like you close your db connection immediately upon it opening.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want your database connection closed. But you are closing it `mongoose.connection.close()`. Don't close your database connection.